# Fetch Facebook album cover photo - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try fetch album datas from facebook and i use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album/picture) method for fetch album cover photo. i get response like this;

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000�Photoshop"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}

What's that's mean ? How can i get image url or image ?
Code is here :

```
   for(final FbAlbumItem f: albums){
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("type", "small");
        new Request(
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                "/"+f.getAlbumId()+"/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        /* handle the result */
                        Log.i("SocialManager", "" + response);
                        JSONObject obj = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

                        try {

                          JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject("albums").getJSONObject("data");
                            String url = o.getString("url");
                           f.setImageUrl(url);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

FbAlbumItem :
`String albumId;
 String albumName;
 String albumCover;
 String imageUrl;`

Comment: Can you show us the code which fetches the data?

Comment: update question check it please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I use my method with some change. Add this parameter

> ```
>         Bundle params = new Bundle();
>         params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
> ```

Thanks for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite - `user_photos` permission for non public albums

Get it with the `cover_photo` field

```
me/albums/album_id?fields=cover_photo
```

Doc reference [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album)

Answer (score 1):

U could have done like this.

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        final String authToken = session.getAccessToken();
        // saveToPreferences(ApplicationData.FB_TOKEN, authToken);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("height", "400");
        params.putString("type", "normal");
        params.putString("width", "400");
        /* make the API call */
        new Request(
                session,
                "/me/albums/{album-id}",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        //cover_photo_fetch = response.cover_photo.toString();
                        Log.d("Picture", response.toString());
                        try {
                            userModel = UserModel.getInstance(mContext);
                            personPhotoUrl = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks ,but This code give me a profile picture. I need  album cover photo. how can i fetch it?

Comment: see my edits. I edited as per facebook documentation.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums/